# Copy initial graph

Tags: java, graph

I want to copy my into another graph so that modifying new graph doesn't affect the initial graph. I know that I'm doing it with passing by value, but what can I do to avoid this?

```
public Graph copyGraph(Graph initialGraph) {
    Graph newGraph = new Graph();
    for(int i = 0; i < initialGraph.getVerticesSize(); i++) {
        Vertex v2 = initialGraph.getVertices().get(i);          
        newGraph.getVertices().set(i, v2);
    }
    return newGraph;
}
```

Comment: You don't want to use the same `Vertex`, you would need copy method or constructor for those as well.

Comment: show us how you declare your `Graph` and `Vertex` classes, `clone()` may work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good except:

```
Vertex v2 = initialGraph.getVertices().get(i);          
newGraph.getVertices().set(i, copyVertex(v2));
```

You need to copy the vertexes as well, similar to your graph-copy.
Copying the graph and using the same vertexes generates not a real copy.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the copy constructor of Graph is properly implemented, `initialGraph` is already a copy of the argument you pass to that function as you pass this argument by copy.

Also I can't imagine how this could work:

```
Graph newGraph = new Graph();
```

`new Graph()` returns a **pointer to** graph, not a Graph.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `clone()` method in this case, in order to not referencing the same objects:

```
public Graph copyGraph(Graph initialGraph) {
     Graph newGraph = initialGraph.clone();
     for(int i = 0; i < initialGraph.getVerticesSize(); i++) {
          Vertex v2 = initialGraph.getVertices().get(i).clone();          
          newGraph.getVertices().set(i, v2);
     }
     return newGraph;
}
```

If `Vertex` contains references to other objects, then that need to be cloned as well, which leads to `deep copying`.

**EDIT**

Your classes should implement `Cloneable` and support `clone()` method.

```
public Object clone() {
    try {
        return super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Another trouble - it says thath clone() method is not visible, so I can't use it

Answer (score -1):

A very crude (but quick) solution to copy a graph would be:

```
    DirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> graph = new DefaultDirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
    DirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> revGraph = new EdgeReversedGraph<>(graph);
    DirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> graphCopy = new EdgeReversedGraph<>(revGraph);
    //To reduce the memory complexity
    revGraph = null;
```

However, it is to be kept in mind that the solution would have high memory & computation complexity if the graph is too big. Discarding the intermediate reversed graph would improve the solution.